# passing parameters to function affect previous call of the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I ran into an issue in JavaScript, I tried searching for a solution but I guess I just don't know exactly what I'm searching for - therefor since I could not find an answer to my problem I'm asking for some help here:

I have 2 JavaScript functions which are supposed to simulate a loading page on ajax call just by adding an overlay div and changing the css state of the cursor to loading, then back to normal:

```
function LoadMouse(ths){
    if($("#overlay").length==0){
        $("body").css({"cursor":"wait"});
        $(ths).css({"cursor":"wait"});
        $("body").append(\'<div id="overlay"></div>\');    
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

function AutoMouse(ths,Cursor){
    if (typeof Cursor === "undefined"){ Cursor = "auto"; }
    $("body").css({"cursor":Cursor});
    $(ths).css({"cursor":Cursor});
    $("#overlay").remove();  
}
```

In my code I'm calling this function from jQuery in various places, for example:

```
function doFirstThing(){
    $(document).on("click",".element1",function(){
        var This = $(this);
        LoadMouse(This);

       //do stuff

       AutoMouse(This);
    });
}

function doSecondThing(){
    $(document).on("click",".element2",function(){
        var This = $(this);
        LoadMouse(This);

       //do stuff

       AutoMouse(This,"pointer");
    });
}
```

The idea is if element2 had a pointer cursor in the css in the first place - I want it to become a pointer once again.

Now say I call the function on element2 - it works and the cursor changes to a pointer but when I click on element1 the cursor changes to auto for both element1 and element 2, if I click element 3 it will change for elements 1,2 and 3 and so on. How can I fix this problem?

(by the way I'm changing the css on both the body and the element because when I tried it only for the body it would not change on the element itself).

EDIT:

In response to the comment about the html: its just a simple  tag:

```
<a href="javascript:void" class="elemen1">click here</a>
<a href="javascript:void" class="elemen2" style="cursor:pointer;">click here 2</a>
```

when I click element 2, and run my LoadMouse button passing 2 parameter into it, the following happens when inspecting the element in chrome:

step 1:(when LoadMouse() runs):

```
<a href="javascript:void" class="elemen2" style="cursor:wait;">click here 2</a>
```

step 2:(when AutoMouse() runs):

```
<a href="javascript:void" class="elemen2" style="cursor:pointer;">click here 2</a>
```

But afterwards when I click on element 1 the second elements inline css is affeced as well:

step 1:(when LoadMouse() runs):

```
<a href="javascript:void" class="elemen1" style="cursor:wait;">click here</a>
<a href="javascript:void" class="elemen2" style="cursor:wait;">click here 2</a>
```

step 2:(when AutoMouse() runs):

```
<a href="javascript:void" class="elemen1" style="cursor:auto;">click here</a>
<a href="javascript:void" class="elemen2" style="cursor:auto;">click here 2</a>
```

Comment: Your problem is happening because of the css being added to the body.  When I run your code (with my own html since you didn't provide any) it works fine if the body css is removed.  I can inspect the elements and see the the cursor css is being applied.  Can you update your question with the minimum html required to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I added the html its just a simple a tag

Comment: You say "when I click element 2, and run my LoadMouse button passing 2 parameter into it"... I must be missing something.  I don't see you calling LoadMouse with multiple parameters.  Can you create a jsfiddle?